# Gradle File Issue: Android studio 2.2 beta 1 Error : Failed to resolve: com.android.databinding:library:1.2.1

Tags: android, android-studio, data-binding, android-databinding, android-studio-2.2

I updated Android studio and after that my project stopped building with errors in the gradle file:

```
Error:Failed to resolve: com.android.databinding:library:1.2.1
<a href="openFile:D:/code/TwoWayDataBindingExample/app/build.gradle">Open File</a><br><a href="open.dependency.in.project.structure">Show in Project Structure dialog</a>
```

The same error appears for me even if I create a brand new project and only activate data binding with the setting:

```
dataBinding{
    enabled = true
}
```

How do I fix this?

---

SDK: 24 preview 2

platform tool:  24.0.1

sdk-tools: 25.2.1 rc1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try updating the Google repository in the Android SDK. The easiest way to do it is to go `Help>Check for Updates...`.

Failing that, I'd report the bug to http://b.android.com/

Comment: I think I use latest

Comment: Yep, you was right. I update all the stuff but forget about repository =(

Answer (score 0):

You can **update "Android Support Repository"**.